# Do all non-mechanical drives use Flash Memory?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

I would like to know this because there is a precaution not to defrag drives that use flash memory as it would decrease their lifespan. Correct my understanding if I'm wrong:

> Mechanical drives: Hard Disk Drives, External USB Disk Drive

> Non-mechanical drives: NVMe M.2 Drive, SSD (Solid State Drive), SATA M.2 Drive, USB Flash Drive/Thumb Drive

Also can you run chkdsk (Windows)/fsck (Linux) safely on all non-mechanical drives?

Comment: wear leveling on SSDs actually fragments the data to keep all areas of the drive written to evenly.  Defragmenting such a drive would be pointless and impossible.

Comment: Note that the term "flash" is broadly misused… but misusing it this way you can essentially call all non-spinning drives 'flash' & treat them all the same way. Don't defrag, do fsck if necessary.

Comment: I think i should rephrase the question to: "Do all non-mechanical drives use flash Memory?" As flash drive might mean the USB thumb drive..

Comment: If you consider only "current market state", yes, there are either mechanical drives (HDDs, optical, tape) or flash-based drives. But in the broad sense no, somebody could invent a new technology which could be not mechanical and not flash.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov: Intel sells SSDs based on 3D XPoint technology (aka Optane), which is not Flash.

Comment: Agreed. I forgot Optane is not flash. Also there is ReRAM, MRAM and so on. But this only strengthens my argument. It seems to have at least 100k write cycle endurance, which is much better than MLC or deeper NAND of SSDs and in the order of that of SLC NAND or NOR flash memory. I.e. it is harder to wear out. Still, worse than HDD and we generally treat is as a flash.

Comment: But so far, only mechanical drives should be defragged? (As defragging is only meant for drives with moving parts in general)? or does Optane need to be defragged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All non-mechanical drives are for sure not all Flash drives (meaning, traditionally USB Keys). If by "flash" you mean Solid State, then yes. SSD drives are inexorably replacing Hard Drives in computers. Both my main computers are SSD only.

It makes no point to run Defrag on any SSD (external or internal) as there is no real "defragmentation" on SSD. Data goes in the memory cells.

Schedule TRIM to run automatically on internal drives to clear previously used and deleted contents. I never bothered with TRIM on Flash Drives (disposable) but you could run it on an External USB drive.

You can used CHKDSK on an SSD drive because CHKDSK is checking for corrupt contents. So that will work.

> there is a precaution not to defrag flash drives as it would decrease
> their lifespan

There is not any real point to trying to defrag something that is not fragmented, so do not try to do this.

However a really good SSD drive will take sustained writes before its end of life (no more write capability) well beyond the lifespan of a normal computer.

I use Virtual Machines on my SSD drive (now into its 5th year) without issue even though VMs do a lot of writing as does the Host machine.

Comment: >All non-mechanical drives are for sure not all flash drives
So does that mean M.2 drives can also be not flash drives? However in general there is no need for defragging non-mechanical drives because there is nothing moving...

Comment: I have not normally heard a large SSD drive to be a Flash drive. Terminology only. If by "flash" you mean solid state, then yes. I just have not heard flash used this way. I clarified my post.

Comment: yes I meant flash = solid state haha. I got into thinking that if a M.2 Drive was not made out of Flash memory, then what else is it made out of?

Comment: USB keys and SSD drives are constructed of memory cells. A 2 TB SSD drive (in my desktop computer) outside of the case) is only a bit bigger than a USB key.

Comment: @avg9957: Intel offers M.2 SSDs based on 3D XPoint techonology (aka Optane), for example. That would be one example of an M.2 SSD that does not use Flash.

Answer (score 2):

> Do all non-mechanical drives use Flash Memory?

No. There are many different non-mechanical storage technologies, for example ReRAM, MRAM, FeRAM, PRAM, etc. While most of these are still in development and/or relegated to niche markets such as radiation-resistant military / space hardware, there is at least one non-mechanical storage technology that has entered the mainstream which is not based on (NAND-)Flash-EEPROM: 3D XPoint technology by Micron and Intel, better known under Intel's marketing name *Optane*.

Intel offers both Optane chips on motherboards that are used as kind of a non-volatile cache and need special support by the chipset and the OS, as well as more standard storage devices such as SAS-, SATA-, or NVMe-protocol SSDs with PCIe-, SAS-, SATA-, U.2-, or M.2-connectors.

> I would like to know this because there is a precaution not to defrag drives that use flash memory as it would decrease their lifespan.

This applies specifically to Flash, not necessarily to other types of non-mechanical / solid-state storage. NAND Flash has a limited number of erase/write cycles, so needlessly writing to Flash does indeed reduce its lifespan.

It also doesn't make sense because Flash-based storage devices perform *wear-leveling* in their controller firmware, which means they deliberately *spread out* writes across the physical medium. In other words, it doesn't matter if you defragment your filesystem or not, because the data will be splattered all over the physical medium anyway.

The purpose of defragmenting is to minimize *mechanical movements* of the read/write head in a mechanical storage device. It has no use in non-mechanical devices.

> Correct my understanding if I'm wrong:
>
> > Mechanical drives: Hard Disk Drives, External USB Disk Drive

This is not correct. For example, an External USB Disk Drive could easily be built using a Flash-based SSD.

> Non-mechanical drives: NVMe M.2 Drive, SSD (Solid State Drive), SATA M.2 Drive, USB Flash Drive/Thumb Drive

This is a tough one. M.2 only specifies the physical and electrical interface for expansion devices. I *think* it would be possible to build a mechanical M.2 drive.

Also, as mentioned above, while SSDs are always non-mechanical, they are not always Flash.

> Also can you run chkdsk (Windows)/fsck (Linux) safely on all non-mechanical drives

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Usual well-known benifit from defragmentation is putting same file parts together, so continuous reading of a file doesn't need slow seeking process, thereby increasing performance. Of course, only rotating drives use seeking, so this applies only to them. For SSDs and Flash drives there is absolutely no difference if parts of a file stored in a consecutive blocks or not. More, actual physical allocation of blocks on the SSD may differ from what is exposed to the system, this is done to wear all blocks equally by the flash translation layer in a controller.

But defrag also needs to read and write blocks to put them together, and each write wears flash memory, so yes, by defragging such drive you reduce its life span, without gains.

This is not entirely true, because this is not the single improvement defragmentation could introduce, but others are subtle. For example, if the disk under questions is a virtual disk in some VM, you may get better I/O efficiency if it there is less fragmentation. Or, if your free space is less fragmented your OS kernel filesystem driver might do space allocation faster. But such gains are very subtle if there are any.

Almost all mainstream filesystems out there (NTFS, EXT4) are desinged with rotating drives in mind. They continue to do "HDD-friendly" allocation even on SSD, which may be inefficient. Probably the world needs new file systems, designed with SSD in mind, which will be more efficient, also considering SSD features to wear them less.

2. `chkdsk` and `fsck` are software to check a file system consistency. That may be required regardless on which device filesystem is on. If file system is corrupted somehow, you must fix it, otherwise you won't be able to use it. So even while it may incur some wear, data is more important and you will run it anyway. However, if file system is clean and intact, it will hardly do any writes, only reads, so it won't wear it. A maximum it might do is to record current time (when check occured) into superblocks.

It could be said if a device itself is buggy, fixing could destroy a file system more. But it doesn't depend on device type.

Comment: APFS is a filesystem designed specifically for SSDs, btw.

Comment: I said "mainstream". There are plenty of such file systems, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems#File_systems_optimized_for_flash_memory,_solid_state_media , but none of them are mainstream. APFS is not mainstream too; is is for Mac only, and I think it accounts for less than 0.1% of SSD data storage in the world. Just count servers, all of these huge cloud storage — how many MacOS are there? And I disagree about ZFS being in that list; you can well put EXT4 journal on flash too, that doesn't make it "flash friendly". ZFS is not designed for flash.

Comment: I think your figures are well out. It may account for 20% of all formatted structures. Don't forget iOS uses it too.

Comment: I am sure Amason S3 alone stores much more data than all macOS and iOS devices all together. So no. Also consider Android devices, if you about iOS, which are again, widespread.

Comment: No-one mentioned data capacity.

Comment: I undestand you're a fan, but open your eyes. Most servers run Linux, some run Windows. VMWare often, it uses its own "VMFS". There are very little Mac servers and Mac virtual machines. I never encounter any of them. And note, servers have multi-terabyte storage. More capable than all these little iphones and so on. Less "beautiful" and "appealing", I admit, there are only some text-based shell, no fancy GUI, but their disks are much, much larger than those of iphones or macbooks. Also, flash cards of digital cameras; none of them use APFS. It can't be a mainstream. Even 0.1% is too much.

Comment: Wow, did someone scare you by mentioning Apple? That's a bit much of a reaction for me. I'm done with this discussion.